# elasticsearch function_score returning unexpected scores

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am receiving different _scores while using different approaches, but I am expecting same results.

First approach is using script_score, multiplying _score with field value, and replacing final _score with calculated one with boost_mode = replace

```
   {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "body",
                "fields": ["title", "text", "keywords"],
                "operator": "and"
            }
        },
        "functions": [{
            "script_score": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "groovy",
                    "inline": "_score * doc['power'].value"
                }
            }
        }],
        "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
}
```

Second one is using  script_score return just field value, and letting engine calculate _score by using boost_mode = multiply

```
   {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "body",
                "fields": ["title", "text", "keywords"],
                "operator": "and"
            }
        },
        "functions": [{
            "script_score": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "groovy",
                    "inline": "doc['power'].value"
                }
            }
        }],
        "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
```

Why is query returning different _scores?

Comment: i am getting the same score as expected, using replace or multiply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in your scores could be because of [Query Normalization Factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#query-norm)

> The query normalization factor (queryNorm) is an attempt to normalize
>   a query so that the results from one query may be compared with the
>   results of another.

Even though the intent of the query norm is to make results from different queries comparable, it doesn’t work very well. The only purpose of the relevance _score is to sort the results of the current query in the correct order. You should not try to compare the relevance scores from different queries.

Now,

> multiply : query score and function score is multiplied
>
> replace : only function score is used, the query score is ignored

When you are using `boost_mode=multiply`, the query score is being normalized whereas when you use `boost_mode=replace`, the score is being replaced with the `function score`, query score is being ignored hence no normalization on query score